# Appending results from LINQS query to paged list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure a simple fix but I can't seem to find a fix for the issue I'm having. The idea is that it would loop through the "extensions" and find the results for them all and I need to append the results at the end but everything I have tried doesn't seem to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
string s = cdr.callingPartyNumber;
string[] exts = s.Trim().Split(',');
foreach (string ext in exts)
{

    var calls = db.CallDetails.Where(x => x.dateTimeConnect >= cdr.dateTimeConnect && x.dateTimeDisconnect <= cdr.dateTimeDisconnect && x.callingPartyNumber.Contains(ext)).Select(x =>
        new CallDetailDTO
        {
            origSpan = x.origSpan,
            callingPartyNumber = x.callingPartyNumber,
            callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID = x.callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID,
            originalCalledPartyNumber = x.originalCalledPartyNumber,
            dateTimeConnect = x.dateTimeConnect,
            duration = x.duration
        })
        .ToList();


    cdr.TotalResults = cdr.TotalResults + calls.Count;
    cdr.Calls = calls.ToPagedList(cdr.Page, pageSize);
}
```

Comment: if adding multiple extensions, it will only collect the results of the last extension. I have looked around to find the best way of appending the results of each extension that is run thru the foreach loop and have had no luck in figuring out the solution.

Comment: What is the `cdr` variable?

Comment: I am using MVC 4, and cdr is my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you only see the last `calls` is because you keep overriding `cdr.Calls` in each iteration:

```
cdr.Calls = calls.ToPagedList(cdr.Page, pageSize);
```

Im assuming `cdr.Calls` is some sort of `List<CallDetailDTO>`.

What you need to do is make it a `List<List<CallDetailDTO>>`  and use `List.Add` for each `ext`:

```
cdr.Calls.Add(calls.ToPagedList(cdr.Page, pageSize));
```